# Difference between 'has done wrong' and 'has been wronged'

Tags: phrase-usage, passive-voice

Recently I came across the below statement in a quote.

> "In a crisis when one **has done wrong**, wrong repentance is required. When one **has been wronged**, a vigorous defense must be mounted"

What is the difference between "has done wrong" and "has been wronged"?

Comment: "has done wrong" means, he literally "did" something bad/wrong, but "has been wrong" does NOT imply that he did something, he just had a wrong/bad idea or he was wrong about what he was thinking.

Comment: Check your source - I think you've got an extra *wrong* in there. It should be "...when one has done wrong, repentance is required".

Answer (score 5):

## Passive Voice: "one" as object of action

> When one **has been wronged**, a vigorous defense must be mounted

In this sentence, the verb "[to wrong](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wrong#Verb)", meaning "to do something bad to someone", is used in the **[Passive Voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_voice).**

Let's illustrate:

> John **wronged** Jim. (Meaning: John did something wrong to Jim)

Here, the same verb is used in the **[active voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_voice)**. Let's remodel to the **passive voice**:

> Jim **was wronged** by John. (Meaning: John did something wrong to Jim; the verb is in the Passive Voice)

Here, the meaning is the same. We can change **was** to **has been**, shifting the tense from Past Simple to Present Perfect:

> Jim **has been wronged** by John. (Meaning: John has done something wrong to Jim)

Finally, we can remove "by John", because the Passive Voice makes emphasis on what has happened to a person, and this makes the mention of the *agent* (John) less important:

> Jim **has been wronged**. (Meaning: Someone has done something wrong to Jim)

---

## Active voice: "one" as agent

> In a crisis when one **has done wrong**, wrong repentance is required.

Here, the Active Voice is used. The meaning is: Someone ("one") has done something wrong, hence, a repentance is required.

Comment: Nice answer! +1 for a step-by-step explanation. Even I learned good things here!

Comment: Good answer. Worth noting that using "wrong" as a verb (e.g. "John wronged Jim" etc) comes across as rather formal/old-fashioned.

Answer (score 2):

In

> In a crisis when one has done wrong, wrong repentance is required.

*wrong* means something "one" actually did. But in

> When one has been wronged, a vigorous defense must be mounted.

*wrong* means something was done to "one". In this example it seems to be about being accused of something unjustly, hence the "vigorous defense".

Answer (score 1):

Has done wrong vs has been wronged

If somebody has done wrong, it means that he has done something that is not honest, legal or morally acceptable.

If somebody has been wronged, it means that he has been treated in an unfair or unacceptable way.